# Exit event handler with MessageBox OK button

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a small winforms application and I have an event handler attached to a button. In the `BtnOk_click` event I check the condition if the value of a text box is "" or it has it's default value and I show a message box.
I am struggling to find a way to exit the event upon closing the message box.

I tried with `Close()` but I don't want my entire form to close, just to exit the event handler.

```cs
private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
 //when the user presses the OK button on the GUI
{
    pcName = txtBoxPcName.Text;
    if((pcName == "") || (pcName == "PC Name"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Computer name cannot be \"" + pcName + "\". \nPlease enter a valid computer name!");
        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //how do I exit the event handler and return back to my main form?
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
    ... // some other code continues here
}
```

After I press the OK button on the message box, the code continues beyond the else{} else condition.

Comment: just do a `return;`

Comment: It's better to disable the OK button until you have valid input rather than put up messages. Then make it clear on the UI what the valid text should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `return` to exit your `void` method (event handler):

```
if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    return;
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return